# Javascript: How to change attributes of child elements?

Tags: javascript, attributes

I have this hidden link, which is needed for other purposes:

```
<span id="notitle" style="display: none;">
<a href="...Foo" title="Foo" style="..."></a>
</span>
```

The link is generated dynamically and automatically includes the title attribute. But I'd like to remove the title attribute since the value is copied when the user copy-pastes surrounding text.

I thought of using javascript. This is what I've got so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function notitle() {
            var mylist=document.getElementById("notitle")
            var listitems= mylist.getElementsByTagName("a")
            for (i=0; i<listitems.length; i++) {
              listitems.setAttribute("title", "");
            }
      }
        </script>
    </head>

<body onLoad="notitle()">

<p>Before hidden link:
<span id="notitle" style="display: none;">
<a href="#Foo" title="Foo">This Link should have no title attribute</a>
</span>
After hidden link.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But doesn't work. I guess it's about `listitems.setAttribute("title", "");`
Any idea? Cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

listitems is the collection, so your code is probably throwing an error.

Anyway, you want:

```
listitems[i].setAttribute("title", "");
```

Comment: +1.  You could also use [ `removeAttribute("title")` ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeAttribute)

Comment: That's even better. Now I saw it only works for the first time, but not on following links like that. How would I apply that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to select the one specific item by using `listitems[i]`, second, I think you can do it as simple as this:

```
listitems[i].title = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `i` index:

```
listitems[i].setAttribute("title", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing

```
listitems.setAttribute("title", "");
```

i times.

Add an array index into the list.